# Draw canvas and change its size dynamically with react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I want to measure the dimensions of a canvas parent element - remeasure the canvas element and then draw.
Is this possible using a single hook? I dont want to use any external packages.

The useLayoutEffect hook works fine with a fixed width and height.

Things I've tried:

1. using the useEffect hook alone and a combination of these two.
2. passing the width and the height as a prop

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

export default props => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setWidth(ref.current.clientWidth);
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
    const context = canvas.current.getContext('2d');

    // some canvas stuff..
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(0,height/2)
    context.lineTo(width, height/2)
    context.stroke()
  }, []);

  const displayWidth = Math.floor(pixelRatio * width);
  const displayHeight = Math.floor(pixelRatio * height);
  const style = { width, height };

return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} ref={ref}>
      <canvas
        ref={canvas}
        width={displayWidth}
        height={displayHeight}
        style={style}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am getting as a result a correctly resized **blank** canvas.

Comment: the height is 0?

Comment: the starting state of the height and the width is 0 -  but Ive also tried something bigger (like 400)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this component is next to another div with a standard height

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine - Dont know if its the optimal answer, if its not please leave a comment.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

export default props => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  // responsive width and height
  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(ref.current.clientWidth);
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight > 400 ? ref.current.clientHeight : 400);
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const context = canvas.current.getContext('2d');

    // some canvas stuff..
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(0,height/2)
    context.lineTo(width, height/2)
    context.stroke()
  }, [width, height]);

  const displayWidth = Math.floor(pixelRatio * width);
  const displayHeight = Math.floor(pixelRatio * height);
  const style = { width, height };

return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} ref={ref}>
      <canvas
        ref={canvas}
        width={displayWidth}
        height={displayHeight}
        style={style}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```